# How to set style for a column in an extjs 4 grid

Tags: css, extjs, grid, styles, multiple-columns

I would like to set a columns css style,
but how can i get every third column?

The grid consists of only one row:
[grid http://imageshack.us/a/img703/598/kksm.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img703/598/kksm.png)

I found that it's possible to look after certain cell content,
also i found a method to loop the index of a row, but not for a column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES you can! By using the pseudo class `:nth-child(3n)`.

Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/RfD7e/).

Comment: it works! But now it affects all tables... I know there is something with css i can handle this, mabe you can help?

Comment: Add a class or id to your table, check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/RfD7e/2/).

Comment: If the answer suits you, please check it 'solution', using the 'v' on the left of it.

Comment: ya, i just figured out handling the other tables!